# How to count the number of elements selected in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, directive

If you have a career-box directive like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='career in careers' career-box ng-click="toggleSelected()"> {{ career.name }} </div>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('careerBox', function() {
   return {
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
     scope.selected = false, 

     scope.toggleSelected = function() { 
        element.toggleClass('selected'); 
        if(scope.selected) { 
            scope.selected = false; 
        } else { 
            scope.selected = true; 
        } 
    } 
  }
 };
});
```

Every time a career-box is selected I would like to count the total number of career-boxes selected (selected=true) and enable a button if they are more than 0.

How can I do that in the code?

Comment: any HTML associated with your directive ?

Comment: Yup it's the first line of code in the question. that's all there is a div with ng-repeat.

Comment: What invokes the `toggleSelected` function?

Comment: Just updated the question code, there is a ng-click="toggleSelected()" on the <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to write a custom directive. It can be done with Angular core directives:

```
  vm.selectedCount = function(item) {
    var count=0;
    for (let i=0; i<vm.careers.length; i++) {
      if (vm.careers[i].selected) count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
```

```
<div ng-repeat='career in careers' 
     ng-click="career.selected = !career.selected"
     ng-style="{'background-color': career.selected?'yellow':''}"> 
 {{ career.name }} 
</div>

<hr>Selected count: {{selectedCount()}}
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/qvTLpOBLMr32O4cNa27G?p=preview)

---

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").controller("myVm", function($scope) {
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.careers = [ {name: "Police Officer", value: 1},
                 {name: "Nurse", value:2},
                 {name: "Doctor", value:3},
               ];
  vm.selectedCount = function(item) {
    var count=0;
    for (let i=0; i<vm.careers.length; i++) {
      if (vm.careers[i].selected) count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
})
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myVm">
    <h1>Selected Div Example</h1>
    <div ng-repeat='career in careers' 
         ng-click="career.selected = !career.selected"
         ng-style="{'background-color': career.selected?'yellow':''}"> 
     {{ career.name }} 
    </div>
  
    <hr>Selected count: {{selectedCount()}}
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a select element with the `multiple` property:

```
<select name="carers" multiple id="multipleCarers" ng-model="data.multipleCarers">
  <option ng-repeat="career in careers" value="{{career.value}}">
    {{career.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

After of that, you can get the count of options selected:

```
{{data.multipleCarers.length}}
```

Comment: It's not really a <select> what I need though. They are <div> boxes that when clicked (selected) get highlighted. Is there a way to count the number of highlighted boxes?

Comment: Try using a function that tracks a count with `ng-click` on the div

Comment: Good idea! Thanks for the suggestion